# Regex no pattern do input não é válida, mas a expressão é funcional

Tags: javascript, html5, regex

Tenho um campo num formulário que só pode aceitar URLs do Youtube ou do Vimeo.
Tendo isso, encontrei a seguinte regex:

```
(?:(?i)(?:https:|http:)?\/\/)?(?:(?i)(?:www\.youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|watch\?v=)|youtu\.be\/|youtube\.googleapis\.com\/v\/)(?<YoutubeID>[a-z0-9-_]{11,12})|(?:vimeo\.com\/|player\.vimeo\.com\/video\/)(?<VimeoID>[0-9]+))
```

Testada aqui: https://regex101.com/r/PVdjg0/2

Porém, ao adicionar essa REGEX no input via atributo `pattern`, a mesma está aceitando qualquer URL.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type='url' required pattern='(?:(?i)(?:https:|http:)?\/\/)?(?:(?i)(?:www\.youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|watch\?v=)|youtu\.be\/|youtube\.googleapis\.com\/v\/)(?<YoutubeID>[a-z0-9-_]{11,12})|(?:vimeo\.com\/|player\.vimeo\.com\/video\/)(?<VimeoID>[0-9]+))' title='URL Vimeo/Youtube.' name='video' placeholder='Video URL' />
            <input type='submit'>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

O que está acontecendo? O que foi feito incorretamente?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema de expressões regulares é que elas não funcionam exatamente da mesma forma em todas as linguagens/*engines*/API's, e um recurso que existe em uma não necessariamente será suportado em outra.

No caso do JavaScript, ele não suporta as [*flags inline*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html), como o `(?i)` (que serve para tornar a expressão *case insensitive*, ou seja, não diferenciar letras maiúsculas de minúsculas). E a [documentação diz que a expressão deve ser uma regex válida em JavaScript, e quando a expressão é inválida, o atributo `pattern` é ignorado.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern)

Inclusive no regex101.com, no menu do lado esquerdo existe a opção *FLAVOR* para você escolher a *engine* de regex. E se você escolher "ECMAScript (JavaScript)", verá que [a expressão de fato é inválida](https://regex101.com/r/55oVZ9/2), por causa do `(?i)`.

Se você retirar esta *flag*, a expressão funciona. Mas ela deixa de ser *case insensitive*, então não vai mais aceitar coisas como "WWW.youTubE.Com", por exemplo:

```html
<form>
  <input id="campo" type="text" pattern="(?:(?:https?:)?\/\/)?(?:(?:www\.youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|watch\?v=)|youtu\.be\/|youtube\.googleapis\.com\/v\/)(?<YoutubeID>[a-z0-9-_]{11,12})|(?:vimeo\.com\/|player\.vimeo\.com\/video\/)(?<VimeoID>[0-9]+))" required />
  <input type="submit" value="ok">
</form>
```

Mudei o trecho `(?:https:|http:)` para `(?:https?:)` (o `s?` indica que a letra "s" é [opcional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html)).

---

Se quiser fazer a validação *case insensitive*, o jeito é fazer fora do `input`:

```js
let regex = /^((?:(?:https?:)?\/\/)?(?:(?:www\.youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|watch\?v=)|youtu\.be\/|youtube\.googleapis\.com\/v\/)(?<YoutubeID>[a-z0-9-_]{11,12})|(?:vimeo\.com\/|player\.vimeo\.com\/video\/)(?<VimeoID>[0-9]+)))$/i;
document.querySelector('#form').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    let url = document.querySelector('#campo').value;
    if (regex.test(url)) return true;

    alert('URL inválida');
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input id="campo" type="text" required />
  <input type="submit" value="ok">
</form>
```

Repare que criei a regex usando `/etc.../i` - o "i" no final indica que ela é *case insensitive*. E também incluí os [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$`, que indicam o início e fim da string, para garantir que o campo só tem o que está especificado pela regex (no atributo `pattern` não é necessário, pois por *default* ele já considera que o campo só pode ter o que está na regex).

Infelizmente não há como fazer de maneira prática no próprio `pattern` do `input`. Uma "solução" (que de tão horrível, eu considero uma gambiarra horrenda, **não use**), seria em vez de `youtube`, colocar `[Yy][Oo][Uu][Tt][uU][Bb][Ee]` (e faça isso para todas as letras que quer *case insensitive*). Mas fica - na minha opinião - ruim demais, eu prefiro a segunda solução sugerida acima, fazendo a validação no JavaScript mesmo, fora do `pattern`.

Mas se quer que **apenas** o ID do vídeo seja *case insensitive*, basta mudar para `(?<YoutubeID>[a-zA-Z0-9-_]{11,12})` - adicionando `A-Z`, ela também considera letras maiúsculas.

Comment: muito obrigado pela explicação! Justamente, achei que regex era "universal", e por isso as inconsistências! Infelizmente, preciso que seja case insensitive, pois os parametros de video do Youtube contem alfanumericos diversos que podem vir maiusculos/minusculos. Vou analisar sua solução e adaptar a minha realidade aqui!

Comment: @MaykelEsser Como eu já disse, no `pattern` não tem como. A menos que você faça uma coisa horrível: para cada letra, coloque a opção maiúscula e minúscula, ou seja, em vez de `youtube`, ficaria `[Yy][Oo][Uu][Tt][uU][Bb][Ee]` - enfim, uma solução bem "nojenta", mas que "funciona" (nesse caso, eu prefiro fazer no JavaScript mesmo, conforme explicado acima) - de qq forma, atualizei a resposta com essa opção horrível :-)

Comment: *O problema de expressões regulares é que elas não são regulares* hahaha

Comment: @MaykelEsser Se quer que **apenas** o ID do vídeo seja case insensitive (e o resto da URL não, ou seja, o www.youtube.com), dá pra usar `(?<YoutubeID>[a-zA-Z0-9-_]{11,12})` - atualizei a resposta, coloquei essa opção no final. Senão, só usando a "solução horrível"

Comment: Sim sim, seria somente o ID do video insensitive. Geralmente o usuário vai copiar e colar a URL, então é o suficiente. Vou testar aqui!

Comment: @Woss Pior é que elas não são mesmo: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36283119

Comment: @hkotsubo funcionou direitinho com o teu último ajuste! <3